# C++ beginner mistake: primary-expression error

Tags: c++

This is the error I get:

> expected primary-expression before `double` 
>  
>        `void Foo_main(Foo* foo){ foo->main(double); }`

This is the code I have:

```
class Foo {
public: int main(double offset) {
    *some code*
     }
}

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_main(Foo* foo){ foo->main(double offset); }
};
```

When I delete the  `double offset` from both places it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably need this:

```
void Foo_main(Foo* foo, double offset){ foo->main(offset); }
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. :)